# How to convert nested map to bean?

Tags: java

When I have beans and map structure like below

```java
public class MyBean1 {
    private String a1;
    private String b1;
    private List<MyBean2> c1;

    public void setA1(String a1) {
        this.a1 = a1;
    }

    public void setB1(String b1) {
        this.b1 = b1;
    }

    public void setC1(List<MyBean2> c1) {
        this.c1 = c1;
    }
}

public class MyBean2 {
    private String a2;
    private String b2;

    public void setB2(String b2) {
        this.b2 = b2;
    }

    public void setA2(String a2) {
        this.a2 = a2;
    }
}

public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    Map<String, Object> map = new HashMap<>();
    map.put("a1", "a1");
    map.put("b1", "b1");
    Map<String, Object> nmap1 = new HashMap<>();
    nmap1.put("a2", "a2");
    nmap1.put("b2", "b2");
    map.put("c1", Collections.singletonList(nmap1));
}
```

If I want get bean with field c1 with type `List<MyBean2>`, how can I convert this map?
I have already try to use `BeanUtils.populate()` in apache-commons-beanutils, but it will erase the type `MyBean2` and get `HashMap`.
Can I use java reflect to do this? or is there any lib can archive my request?
What if the type is not `List` but `Map`? Or other generic type like `Optional`?
By the way, I do not want to use json lib or pre-define structure lib like MapStruct or Dozer.

Comment: Try Jackson [ObjectMapper.convertValue](https://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-databind/javadoc/2.12/com/fasterxml/jackson/databind/ObjectMapper.html#convertValue-java.lang.Object-java.lang.Class-) (not sure if it would work, but it might)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper, Just add below in your main method and you can get the Map as the desired object , Please see the screen shot for example (Local run in debug mode)-

```
        ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
        final MyBean1 myBean1 = mapper.convertValue(map, MyBean1.class);
        System.out.println(myBean1);
```

[image]

Comment: This will use json serializer to convert map. But also I found there is no good way to use reflect to do this. Maybe this is the best way for now. Thanks!